# R terra/raster: uploading a netcdf file alters resolution

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4, terra

I have netcdf files (GPM IMERG precipitation) which are supposed to be at0.1x0.1 resolution like in the red box at the bottom here:

[image]

Well the pixel size is not exactly 0.1 on the image, but at least its height and width are the same.

However when uploading the netcdf via `terra::` or `raster::` the resolution slightly changes:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 185, 97, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.09999998, 0.1000001  (x, y)
extent      : 34.2, 43.9, 62.3, 80.80002  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : _(1).nc:precipitationCal 
varname     : precipitationCal (Daily accumulated precipitation (combined microwave-IR) estimate) 
name        : precipitationCal 
unit        :               mm 
time (days) : 2000-06-04
```

Any solution on how to transform the rasters in R back to their original resolution would be welcomed. Btw, does this has to do with rounding coordinates of the extent in R packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you point to that file? From what I can see, either the extent or the resolution shown on the website is wrong. Based on these numbers, it should be:

```
print((43.9000038 - 34.20000855) / 97, digits=10)
#[1] 0.09999995103
```

Perhaps for the website the resolution was computed using the center of the cells, so that you get

```
print((43.95 - 34.15) / 97, digits=10)
#[1] 0.1010309582
```

It is hard to be sure without the file. But I would put my money on the website being wrong.

---

With your file I also see this

```
f <- "__1_.nc"
r <- rast(f)
res(r)
#[1] 0.09999998 0.10000007
```

But that is correct in the sense that that does reflect the x and y coordinates written to the file. The x and y coordinates for the cells that are provided are not strictly regular (but nearly so). For example, here are the first and last three y coordinates:

```
62.3500022888184 62.4500083923340 62.5499992370605 ...  
80.5500030517578 80.6500091552734 80.7500152587891
```

From the file alone I cannot say whether these small decimals are intentional or stem from sloppiness, I assume the latter and in that case it indeed seems reasonable to round the extent:

```
ext(r) <- round(ext(r), 4)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 185, 97, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
#extent      : 34.2, 43.9, 62.3, 80.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : __1_.nc:precipitationCal 
#varname     : precipitationCal (Daily accumulated precipitation #(combined microwave-IR) estimate) 
#name        : precipitationCal 
#unit        :               mm 
#time (days) : 2000-06-04
```

Comment: the file is accessible here https://filebin.net/yjehizjorst35e71 . The image in my first post is a snapshot of (info) the  file uploaded in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks. I do not see any issue with what terra or raster report. The website is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that amending the extent boundaries corrects the resolution. Here is an extent of the file after uploading:

```
r<-rast("file")
ext(r)

SpatExtent : 34.2000038226446, 43.9000022808711, 62.3000022535739, 80.8000152940335 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Ive rounded the decimals of the extent coordinates and the resolution was coreccted:

```
ext(r)<-c(34.2, 43.9, 62.3, 80.8)

r

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 185, 97, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : 34.2, 43.9, 62.3, 80.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : _(1).nc:precipitationCal 
varname     : precipitationCal (Daily accumulated precipitation (combined microwave-IR) estimate) 
name        : precipitationCal 
unit        :               mm 
time (days) : 2000-06-04
```